# Make my form on top no matter what

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, pinvoke

I need a method that will make my form move to the top when other forms do not want them to.

I am not talking about `myForm.BringToFront` or `myForm.TopMost`.

I am hoping that there is a P/Invoke that I can do to get into the OS and say, "This Form On Top, NO MATTER WHAT".

The reason I am needing this is that I have an app that is occasionally going behind my Device Management app.  The way that app is configured is such that it cannot be minimized.

Any help would be ... helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure about that... If someone else also makes an app whose window is always on top "no matter what" then this causes a contradiction and then the universe will implode. Or perhaps the screen will just flicker really badly. I think it would work though if you changed 'no matter what' to 'in most reasonable circumstances'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055875/always-on-top-window

Comment: @Kate Gregory - um that question is java based.  Mine is windows mobile based....

Comment: Both face the same issue. You want the OS to offer you something that cannot exist. The mechanism by which it would be called is not the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P/Invoke [SetWindowsPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx) with HWND_TOPMOST.